# IIS Application & Virtual Directory usage

Tags: iis

is there any possibility to monitor Application and Virtual Directory usage for IIS site? I need to know if app/direcotry is in use or not.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that information is in the IIS logs.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look to you logfiles. Depending on your Windows version, they may reside in `%windir%\system32\logfiles` or `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs`. IIS Logging (path, details, rollover ...) can be configured directly in your IIS MMC.